# #1062 - Duplicate entry '3-285-42-0' for key 'UNQ_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_INT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'

Tags: magento-1.7, database, backup

I am picking up a site from a predecessor and I am creating a dev version of a live site.
After exporting the site via sequel pro or phpmyadmin (seperate attempts), the import process always bulks at the catalog_category_entity_int table.

Here is the error:

Error
SQL query:

```
-- -- Dumping data for table `catalog_category_entity_int` -- INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 3, 34, 1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 105, 0, 1, 1), (3, 3, 105, 0, 2, 1), (11, 3, 34, 0, 4, 1), (12, 3, 105, 0, 4, 1), (13, 3, 42, 0, 4, 6), (14, 3, 43, 0, 4, 1), (15, 3, 106, 0, 4, 0), (16, 3, 107, 0, 4, 0), (18, 3, 34, 0, 5, 1), (19, 3, 105, 0, 5, 1), (20, 3, 42, 0, 5, NULL), (21, 3, 43, 0, 5, 1), (22, 3, 106, 0, 5, 0), (23, 3, 107, 0, 5, 0), (26, 3, 43, 0, 2, 0), (27, 3, 107, 0, 2, 0), (43, 3, 34, 0, 8, 1), (44, 3, 105, 0, 8, 1), (45, 3, 42, 0, 8, NULL), (46, 3, 43, 0, 8, 1), (47, 3, 106, 0, 8, 0), (48, 3, 107, 0, 8, 0), (57, 3, 34, 0, 10, 1), (58, 3, 105, 0, 10, 1), (59, 3, 42, 0, 10, 6), (60, 3, 43, 0, 10, 1), (61, 3, 106, 0, 10, 0), (62, 3, 107, 0, 10, 0), (64, 3, 34, 0, 11, 1), (65, 3, 105, 0, 11, 1), (66, 3, 42, 0, 11, 21), (67, 3, 43, 0, 11, 1), (68, 3, 106, 0, 11, 0), (69, 3, 107, 0, 11, 0), ([...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '3-285-42-0' for key 'UNQ_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_INT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'

Information:
I have tried exporting the site with Disable foreign keys checked (or adding the lines SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; to start and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; to end)

I know that site was upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7.0.2 at start of the year, other than that the site has not been touched until I have arrived on the scene.

Before the site was exported I had re-indexed the live site, flushed the cache and cache storage, I had also rm -rf removed contents of var/cache and var/session

My question is:
what do I do?
Do I remove the duplicates in sql? (I know its very bad to touch magento db and should be avoided at all costs)
Can I clean the db up with sql query to remove these duplicates?
If I remove these duplicates, will this table have a knock on affect to other tables?

I have asked all my magento pals that I know and each and everyone has been unable to help and I have exhausted my knowledge so far.
If anyone can provide insight, answer my questions or point me in right direction, I would be forever grateful and of course learn how to solve a very peculiar problem.

Comment: have you tried using the console mysqldump tool to export and mysql console tool to import?

Comment: apologies for not putting that in my information. I have tried importing via terminal into localhost and on server and it stops at same line. However I did not export via console, will that make a difference in terms of exporting? or will the output be same as if I were exporting from phpmyadmin or sequel pro?

Comment: Are you turning off key restraints when you try to import?

Comment: Also, is the current site running on 1.7? i.e. you can see the site running?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but maybe it's an answer to your problem. Try exporting the database using the db backup functionality of Magento. `System->Tools->Backup`

Comment: thanks for you're responses. to answer brentwpetersons questions: 
1) turning off key restraints, do you mean disable foreign key checks or add SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; to sql file? I have tried that if so. 2)
The site is live and running. issue is importing the live into a dev setup

Marius: I have not tried that yet but will do later today hopefully. Will edit this response to say how I got on.

thank you both for your responses

Comment: If you have access to the SQL you can select something like this to see if you have two of the same values.
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_int where attribute_id = 42 and entity_id = 285 and entity_type_id = 3; This would show you the duplicate rows. I think getting a stable dump will be more important using either Marius' method or a command like mysqldump

Comment: Unfortunately the ssh export then import did not work either. same error popped up on the terminal command line when I tried to import.
I had been going through removing the duplicates and I think this is going to be course of action. All I need is to get this backup across to the dev so I can update a module and test it doesn't break my site.

thanks once again for responses and advice. Truly appreciate help and will of course pass on help to other posters who encounter this problem. Also if I ever succeed, I too will pass that on too